# Can't get rows in TableLayout to center horizontally

Tags: android, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I can't get the rows in my TableLayout to center on the screen.  I'm trying to create a 4x4 table of clickable images and want them centered on the screen.  It ends of drawing them left aligned, I would like them to be centered with space on either side.  Here is the code I have:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">

        <TableRow android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/rocket"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp" 
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/rocket"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp" 
                android:padding="3dp" 
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/rocket"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp" 
                android:padding="3dp" 
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/rocket"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp" 
                android:padding="3dp" 
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/rocket"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp" 
                android:padding="3dp" />
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/rocket"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp" 
                android:padding="3dp" />
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/rocket"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp" 
                android:padding="3dp" />
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/rocket"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp" 
                android:padding="3dp" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/rocket"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp" 
                android:padding="3dp" />
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/rocket"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp" 
                android:padding="3dp" />
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/rocket"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp" 
                android:padding="3dp" />
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/rocket"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp" 
                android:padding="3dp" />            
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: try changing <TableRow android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
to <TableRow android:gravity="center_horizontal">

if that doesn't work I would add android:width="wrap_content" to the table rows and see if that works

Comment: Changing android:layout_gravity to android:gravity did the trick!  I can't believe I didn't try that one but thanks!  Any ideas on what the difference is?

Answer (score 11):

try with **android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"**  as follows

```
 <TableRow android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
          android:layout_weightsum = "4">

                <ImageView android:src="@drawable/rocket"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp" 
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight = "1" />
                <ImageView android:src="@drawable/rocket"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp" 
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight = "1"  />
                <ImageView android:src="@drawable/rocket"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp" 
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight = "1"  />
                <ImageView android:src="@drawable/rocket"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp" 
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight = "1"  />            
            </TableRow>
```

Comment: android:layout_weightsum  - seems deprecated

Answer (score 6):

Usually we use layout_gravity to align.

try

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

in your code.

`android:gravity` aligns the data to horizontal center.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, bieno002, make sure your `<TableLayout>` has `layout_width` set to `"wrap_content"`. This will give it space to breathe on either side.

Then, just add a `android:layout_gravity="horizontal"` to your `<TableLayout>` node. Like so:

```xml
<TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView (or whatever)>
        <TextView (or whatever)>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```